# How to set a graph-filling-area?

Tags: graphviz, dot

How to set the graph to try to fill the area allocated to it? With an increase in the number of nodes, it simply decreases in size, but also remains in one line, although the vertical size (40) allows placement down. If you remove the rankdir, then it places vertically, but also in one line.

```
digraph "test_graph"{
  rankdir = LR;
  bgcolor = whitesmoke;
  graph [size = "15, 40"];
  node [shape = circle,
        style = filled,
        margin = 0,
        fontsize = 14,
        color = sandybrown];
  edge [fontsize = 10,
        arrowhead = vee];
  1->2 [label = "R"];
  2->3 [label = "R"];
  3->4 [label = "R"];
  3->5 [label = "B"];
  4->1 [label = "R"];
  5->6 [label = "U"];
  6->7 [label = "U"];
  7->8 [label = "U"];
  7->9 [label = "F"];
  8->5 [label = "U"];
  9->10 [label = "F"];
  10->11 [label = "D"];
  11->12 [label = "D"];
  12->13 [label = "D"];
  13->10 [label = "D"];
  13->14 [label = "L"];
  14->15 [label = "L"];
  15->16 [label = "D"];
  16->17 [label = "D"];
  17->18 [label = "D"];
  17->19 [label = "L"];
  18->15 [label = "D"];
  19->20 [label = "F"];
  20->21 [label = "F"];
  21->22 [label = "F"];
  21->23 [label = "L"];
  22->19 [label = "F"];
  23->24 [label = "L"];
  24->25 [label = "F"];
}
```

Comment: You will have to be more precise as to what you want to achieve. What is your desired outcome, how should a "good" result look like?

Comment: Looks like  copy/repost from: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900127/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b0. The (automatic google translated) text is: How to set the graph to try to fill the area allocated to it? With an increase in the number of nodes, it simply decreases in size, but also remains in one line, although the vertical size (40) allows placement down. If you remove the rankdir, it places vertically, but also in one line ..

Comment: @vaettchen, Ideally that 1: edges weren't crossed (I have always a planar graph) 2: That most compactly (it is as much as possible knots) was located on A4 for the printing

Comment: @albert, yes it's a copy of my question, just there on this tag there is nobody, in difference from the English version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to select suitable nodes that

- are connected by one edge
- connect to other nodes in a way that fills the available width as you like it

and then

- connect them in the desired order by invisible edges (so that you avoid graphviz reordering them)
- ranking them on the same lavel so that they appear one below the other

In concrete terms this means that adding

```
1 -> 10 -> 19[ style = invis ];
{ rank = same; 1 10 19 }
```

just before the closing curly brace, as the last two lines, will produce

[image]

which is, as far as I understand your requirement, what you want.